# TinyMCE stripping style tags

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Is there a way to get [TinyMCE V4](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/) to not remove `<style>` tags.

```
  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea.tinymce',
    theme: 'modern',
    plugins: [
      'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker',
      'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
      'save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor'
    ],
    valid_elements: '+*[*]',
    width: '100%',
    inline_styles: true,
    keep_styles: true,
    extended_valid_elements: '+*[*]',
    custom_elements: '*',
    invalid_elements: '',
    verify_html: false
  });
```

I want to be able to add any HTML I want whether valid or not. I don’t care if it is a fork or a workaround.

Answer (score 18):

You can use TinyMCE's `valid_children` option for that:

```
valid_children : '+body[style]',
```

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6LLrcn4z/) for a complete example.

The `valid_children` enables you to control what child elements can exists within specified parent elements.

Answer (score 15):

Define `style` and `link` as a custom tag to keep them:

```
tinymce.init({
...
    extended_valid_elements:"style,link[href|rel]",
    custom_elements:"style,link,~link"
...
});
```

Comment: Man, thanks!, this is the correct answer, i know this tags go inside <head> in this case im using the editor to build email templates on html on a script and this was my salvation to use link with google fonts, Save my day, thanks

Answer (score 1):

face the same question, and add the following code mentioned by Wayne will solve the problem

```
tinymce.init({
...
    custom_elements:"style"
...
});
```

Comment: my tinymce version is V5

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE will only allow HTML tags where they are valid ... the `<style>` tag belongs in the `<head>` of the document so if you place one in the `<body>` it will strip it out.

If you enable the `fullpage` plugin and add a `<style>` tag in the `<head>` TinyMCE will keep the `<style>` tag.

Comment: Right that's actually my whole point is I want to do stuff it's not valid

Comment: @KirkStrobeck - TinyMCE won't allow you to disable the HTML validation aspects of the software.  If it finds invalid HTML it will do its best to clean it up.  If you need to save the styles you can grab them from the head and then store them in your database and re-inject them into the head during content editing - or you can store the entire HTML document and then reload it later.  The real fun comes when you want to render the content outside TinyMCE - you need a process to add the relevant style to the head of the rendered page so the content looks as expected.

Comment: Feels like a failure of the plugin to not allow this customization

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Dekel earlier - adding following line solves the problem:

```
valid_children : '+body[style],-body[div],p[strong|a|#text]'
```

Reference: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#keep_styles