# TinyMCE React strips out <style /> tag when placed inside the <head /> tag

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, tinymce

I am using `TinyMCE React` with `fullpage` and `code` plugins enabled to create email templates. I am trying to insert a `<style />` with custom css classes defined inside the `<head />`. But every time I reload the component, the `<style />` is being stripped out. Here is a simplified exampled:

```
...
<head>
    <style>
         h1 {color:red;}
         p {color:blue;}
    </style>
</head>
```

Is this scenario supported? I have looked at a number of similar issues such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38165362/tinymce-stripping-style-tags?rq=1). They seem to suggest the use of the `valid_children` option. As I understand, this option allows the inclusion of "invalid" tags inside parent tags. But `<style />` inside `<head />` is valid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about how you have TinyMCE configured it is very hard to say what is causing this issue.  I am certainly able to load a style in the head of a document managed by TinyMCE as shown in this TinyMCE Fiddle:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/cPgaab/2

How is your TinyMCE configured?  If you update this fiddle to use your configuration is the style no longer kept?